# Rack middleware insert_before not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rack

I'm trying to use the `SslEnforcer` rack middleware in a Rails 4 project I'm working on. In [the documentation of the gem](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer/#basic-usage), it is said that :

> Cookies should be set before the SslEnforcer processes the headers, but due to the middleware calls chain Rack::SslEnforcer should be inserted before the ActionDispatch::Cookies.

So I've followed the instructions described there, and used this in my `application.rb` file :

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Cookies, Rack::SslEnforcer
```

However, when I run `rake middleware`, I still get this order:

```
$ rake middleware
use Rack::Sendfile
...
...
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
...
...
use Rack::SslEnforcer
...
...
```

**So the `Rack::SslEnforcer` middleware is not inserted before the `ActionDispatch::Cookies` middleware as expected**. I've also tried to do this:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::SslEnforcer
```

which *does* work as expected, and inserts the `Rack::SslEnforcer` middleware first in the middleware stack (but I'm not sure this is a good thing to do?).

---

What am I missing here, do you have any idea why `insert_before` is not working as expected? Thanks for your help :)